# how to run a callback function after $.mobile.changePage is ready in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

in this project im using jquery and phonegap

i have a link that if clicked , changes the page:

```
$('#statsButtonmain').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("stats.html", { transition: "slideup"}, true, true);  
});
```

this works fine, but i would like to run a function (`playMusic()`) when the transition is done, something like this:

```
$('#statsButtonmain').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("stats.html", { transition: "slideup"}, true, true);  
            playMusic();
});
```

i found out that there is a `pageshow` event that gets triggered on the page being shown, after its transition completes, but im not sure how to use it

this doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not done a lot a jQuery mobile development so this might not be the most efficient solution. As you said, the `pageshow` event is what you need to use. Here are the 2 HTML files I ran locally in which I see the alert after the `stats.html` page transition is completed. The `.live()` is bound to the `#stats` element's page `pageshow` event.

#### HTML

(saved as index.html)

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Home</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#statsButtonmain').on('click', function() {
           $.mobile.changePage('stats.html', { transition: 'slideup'}, true, true);  
        });

        $('#stats').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
          playMusic();
        });

        function playMusic() {
          alert('playing music');
        }
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Callback test</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <a href="#" id="statsButtonmain">click me</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(saved as stats.html)

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Stats</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="stats">
    <div data-role="content">some stats</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if i have a script.js and i want to move the code there, would that interfere?

Comment: It will still work if the script is in an external file. I just tried it locally :-) It _should_ work with the [Multi-page template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) as well but I have not tried it that way.

Comment: also, one more thing. In my case i have a `index.html` after the page loads it goes to `test.html` and on that page i have the link to `stats.html`. In this case do i have to put the js in the `test` page of ill leave in in the script.js file and add that file into `test.html`?

Comment: A warning to everyone: `live` is deprecated and it has been removed from jQuery 1.9. I would recommend using `delegate` or `on` instead. See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for details.

Comment: `pageshow` is deprecated in 1.4.0, use `pagecontainershow` just like how to change page, need to use `$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "pageId", {
                transition: 'none'
            });` instead of `changePage` method

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone. It also retains the query string between pages too.

```
async function loadPage(_url) {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    var _query = "";
    if (window.location.href.includes("?")) {
      if (window.location.href.split("?").length >= 2) {
        _query = "?" + window.location.href.split("?")[1];
      }
    }
    $.mobile.changePage(_url + _query);
    var currentPage;
    function checkCurrentPage() {
      if (typeof $("body").pagecontainer != "undefined") {
        currentPage = $("body").pagecontainer("getActivePage");
        if (currentPage[0].baseURI.includes(_url)) {
          clearInterval(loadPageInt);
          resolve();
        }
      }
    }
    var loadPageInt = setInterval(function () {
      checkCurrentPage();
    }, 100);
  });
  return await promise;
}
```

Usage:

```
loadPage('file.html')
.then(() => {
     // do some stuff now the page has changed to file.html
});
```