# how to disappear given loading screen after transition in phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

i am developing an app in which i need to give loading screen till page is transited(navigated) then to stop showing loading screen after navigation.but the loading screen still show even after transition .how to stop showing it after transition?

.html

```
 <div id="loading" class="view" style="text-align: center; margin: auto; display: none;
    z-index: 99; position: fixed;">
    <div class="loadingimg">
        Loading...
    </div>
</div>
```

.js

```
  function gotonextscreen() {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";

        if (location == false) {
            jAlert("Please make sure GPS is enabled. Please try again.");
        }
        else {
             //document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
            $('#iframe').height(screen.height);

            document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = '<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 80%;" width="75%" height="75%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&amp;q=hospital&aq=&amp;sll=' + x + ',' + y + '&amp;sspn=0.040066,0.077162&ie=UTF8&hq=hospital&hnear=&amp;t=m&ll=' + x + ',' + y + '&amp;spn=0.007705,0.008669&z=14&output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=en&geocode=&amp;q=hospital&aq=&amp;sll=' + x + ',' + y + '&amp;sspn=0.040066,0.077162&ie=UTF8&hq=hospital&hnear=&amp;t=m&ll=' + x + ',' + y + '&amp;spn=0.007705,0.008669&z=14" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left"></a></small>';
            $.mobile.changePage('#Page', {
                transition: "none",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
            });
            currentPage = 'Page';
            pageData.push(currentPage);
$('#loading').hide();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You could try using jquery to hide the page $('div#loading').hide(); . Another thing to try would be to specify a callback after the page transition. So when you navigate to the new page the callback will close the loading div. I am just not sure how you pass a callback in $.mobile.changePage.

Comment: @Fido i have added $('#loading').hide(); if i add these loading screen doesnt  even show.Where should i put this hide() function.

Comment: could you try replacing //document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none"; with $('div#loading').hide(); ?

If that does not work then try to use a callback as I previously mentioned.

Comment: @Fido if i use any one of document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none" or  $('div#loading').hide();  loading screen doesnt even show up while loading.Can u please show me how to use callback after page transition in above example

Answer (score 0):

I have not done a lot with jquery mobile but the one option is to try and do a callback after the page loads.

In your case you might try something like:

```
$('#Page').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    $('div#loading').hide();
});
```

Place that before you do your page change and see if it works.
The above snippet essentially binds an event handler on 'liveshow' of '#Page' so when '#Page' renders you can try to hide the loading bar.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326177/how-to-run-a-callback-function-after-mobile-changepage-is-ready-in-jquery) answer provides a nice example of how to do a callback after the page loads.

Comment: @it didnt work but what i found out is that its not taking time to get transit to next page ,it is taking time to load google map.so show and hide of loading signs are working problem is with load of google map.